# Can touching the back of the Raspberry Pi Camera to the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi cause irreparable damage?

Tags: gpio, raspicam

Whilst moving the camera module around through a casing system I accidentally brought the back of the module in contact with the GPIO pins for 3 seconds (roughly). There now appears to be bands of darker colour on the picture produced by the camera. Could this connection have caused damage? Is there anyway I can repair the bands?

Answer (score 1):

Any electrical short circuit as well as electrostatic discharges (ESD) leading to sudden and momentary electric currents that flow between two objects, typically induced by touching it unprotected can (partially) destroy electronic components. Highly integrated circuits such as the processor of the Pi are specifically prone to this destruction.